# Group theory lecture for quantum information

Tags: resource-request

I am looking for a nice lecture about group theory for quantum information. Ideally a video lecture.

I know some of the very basics as I am familiar with the stabilizer formalism but there are many "important" things, for instance, representation theory, which I am not familiar with.

If the lecture can be quantum information-oriented it would be a plus (in order to directly go to the things that are useful for quantum mechanics).

Comment: Nice idea for a lecture course actually!

Comment: [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m8uXQmo2A0U) video by Chris Moore might have some (not necessarily all) of your desirables, with a focus on the hidden subgroup problem especially for graph isomorphism.  Nothing about the stabilizer formulation, but a small amount of representation theory.  It's only one "lecture" (more of a presentation) though.